# Flyway throwing error on migration script

Tags: java, flyway

I'm trying out Flyway to potentially use in our project and so I have an extremely simple migration script. I appear to have set something up incorrectly however - flyway connects to my DB (SQL Server 2008 R2) successfully to create metadata tables, but when I run the script I get

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-maven-plugin:2.2.1:migrate      (default-cli) on project persistence: com.googlecode.flyway.cor
 e.api.FlywayException: Migration of schema [dbo] to version 1.1 failed! Changes successfully rolled back. Incorrect syntax near '?'. -> [Help 1]
```

My script is:

```
 ALTER TABLE msg.Message
 ADD Deleted bit NULL
```

Looking at the debug logs, flyway outputs:

```
 [DEBUG] Executing SQL: ??A L T E R   T A B L E   m s g . M e s s a g e

  A D D   D e l e t e d   b i t   N U L L
```

I don't know where the question marks come from, or why the text has spaces. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not too confident with Flyway, but are you not required to end your SQL statements with a `;`? As your script is a SQL file ...

Comment: Could this be an encoding problem? Flyway expects UTF-8. Which one did you use?

Comment: It was in UTF-8 it turns out - I'm using files generated by SQL Server Management Studio 2008. My individual scripts are running correctly now, but my initial DB migration fails all over. For now I'm just going to handle the initial migration by hand and let Flyway handle the patch scripts.

Comment: Have you tried changing the encoding property to the correct value for your environment?

Comment: I think it was something related to that - it appears to be working fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of output indicates UTF, but in the 16-bit form, with a magic character at the beginning. The ? and spaces are the giveaway.

Several MS tools speak that natively, while most Unix tools use UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the encoding of the sql migration file to UTF-8 solved the '??' error for me.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the encoding for the file worked for me. I used a text editor (Notepad++):

1. Open the file in the text editor.
2. Select 'Encoding' in the menu.
3. Choose the encoding type from the list of options.
4. Save the file.